# Hambuerguer menu not working online but working in xampp/localhost

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, hamburger-menu

I am having a problem with a responsive menu. While I'm in my offline server, the responsive menu works fine in mobile format, but when It's in the real server, it does not work. I've been struggling with this for hours. Here is my code:

HTML

```
    <div class="menu">      
        
        <div class="menu_bar">
            <img id="logo-mobile" src="design/logo-titol-prova-1.PNG">
            <a href="#" class="bt-menu"><span class="icon-menu"></span></a>
        </div>
 
        <nav>
        <img id="logo" src="design/logo-titol-prova-1.PNG">
            <ul>
                <li class="first"><a href="about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="surf-salina-cruz">Surf/Kitesurf</a></li>
                <li><a href="mexico-surf-tour">The Tour</a></li>
                <li><a href="surf-camp-lodging">Lodging</a></li>
                <li><a href="testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
                <li><a href="book-now">Reserve Now</a></li>             
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
/*Menu*/

.menu{ 
    width: 100%; 
    position:fixed; 
    top:0;
    margin:0 auto; 
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .5s;
    z-index:1000;
}

.menu nav {
    display: table;
    max-width:1200px;
    max-width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    z-index:1000;
    -webkit-transition: margin-left .5s;
}
 
.menu_bar {
    display:none;
}
 
.menu nav ul {
 width:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 display: inline;
 list-style:none;
 text-align: center;
}
 
.menu nav ul li {
 display: inline;
 width:100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 padding-left: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 background: url(design/list.png) left no-repeat;
}

.menu nav ul li.first {
 background:none;
}
 
.menu nav ul li a {
 display: inline-block;
 margin:15px 15px 0 15px;
 padding:15px 0;
 color:#303030;
 font-family: 'Dosis';
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration:none;
 letter-spacing:1px;
}
 
.menu nav ul li a:hover {
 color:#ffc000;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: all .5s linear;
 -o-transition: all .5s linear;
 -moz-transition: all .5s linear;
 -webkit-transition: all .5s linear;
}

.menu nav ul li a:active {
  color:#71e1b0;
}
 
section {
 padding:20px;
}
 
img#logo{
    float:left;
    display: block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    -webkit-transition: width .5s;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1100px){
    
    img#logo{
     max-width:300px;
     margin-left: 10px;
    }
    
    .menu{ 
     width: 100%; 
     padding-top:10px;
     padding:0;
     font-size:15px;
     float:right;
    }
    
    .menu nav ul li a {
     margin:10px 15px 0 15px;
    }
    
    .menu nav {
     width:100%;
     max-width:100%;
     margin:0 auto;
     text-align: center;
     z-index:1000;
    }

@media screen and (max-width:800px){
    

    
    img#logo{
     display:none;
    }
    
    .menu nav {
     max-width:250px;
     height:100%;
     right:-100%;
     margin:0;
     position: fixed;
     background: #fff;
    }
    

    .menu nav ul li {
     display:block;
     float:none;
     padding:0;
     background:none;
    }
    
    .menu nav ul li a {
     display:block;
     padding:20px 20px 20px 0;
     margin:0;
     color:#303030;
     font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
     font-size: 15px;
     font-weight:400;
     text-align: right;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     background: none;
     border-right:4px solid #71e1b0;
    }
    
    .menu nav ul li a:hover {
     color:#71e1b0;
     text-decoration: none;
     border-bottom:none;
    }
 
    .menu_bar {
     display:block;
     max-width:100%;
     padding:15px;
     background:#fff;
    }

    .menu_bar .bt-menu {
     display:block;
     padding:20px;
     color:#33e873;
     text-decoration:none;
     text-align:right;
     font-weight:bold;
     font-size:27px;

    }
    
    img#logo-mobile{
     float:left;
     max-width:200px;
     margin: 7px 0 0 10px;
     padding:0;
    }
```

menu.js

```
$(document).ready(main);
 
var contador = 1;
 
function main(){
    $('.bt-menu').click(function(){
        // $('nav').toggle(); 
 
        if(contador == 1){
            $('nav').animate({
                right: '0'
            });
            contador = 0;
        } else {
            contador = 1;
            $('nav').animate({
                right: '-100%'
            });
        }
 
    });
 
}
```

script-menu.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#banner").css({"height":$(window).height() + "px"});

    var flag = false;
    var scroll;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if(scroll > 100){
            if(!flag){
                $("#logo").css({"width": "200px"});

                $(".menu").css({"top":"0", "margin":"0 auto", "padding":"0", "background-color": "#fff", "box-shadow": "0 1px 1px #71e1b0"});
                
                flag = true;
            }
        }else{
            if(flag){
                $("#logo").css({"width": "400px",});

                $(".menu").css({"top":"0", "margin":"0 auto", "padding":"0", "background-color":"transparent", "box-shadow": "none"});
                flag = false;
            }
        }


    });

});
```

This is the website: http://marsurftours.com/. I've tried everything and spent many hours trying to find a solution. If you know how to solve this issue, I would appreciate it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to add `js/` before `menu.js`
So instead

```
<script src="menu.js"></script>
```

Try

```
<script src="js/menu.js"></script>
```

Comment: I solved it, it wasn't a code problem. I didn't upload the right file by accident but thanks to your response I found out about it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to link a file in system storage , you need to link a url

example: [www.stackoverflow.com/navigation.js](http://www.stackoverflow.com/navigation.js)